# Mac os x: How to have makefile reference /Applications/application

Tags: makefile, osx-snow-leopard, carbon-emacs

OS Mac OS X 10.6.6
emacs 23.2.1

I'm currently trying to install magit on carbon emacs using their proposed make solution. I'm an almost complete makefile newby so I might be on the complete wrong path altogether.
Makefile displays:

```
%.elc: %.el
$(BATCH) --eval '(byte-compile-file "$<")'
```

which gets expanded to:

```
emacs -batch -q -no-site-file -eval "(setq load-path (cons (expand-file-name \".\") load-path))" --eval '(byte-compile-file "magit.el")'
```

What I do understand. However it comes back with:

```
Cannot open load file: subst-ksc
```

What after a bit of googling reveals some missing libraries. I also realized that the emacs referenced in the expanded command is pointing to /usr/bin/emacs which is one big file, I don't see the normal lisp / site-lisp / etc directories. I also know that my prefered emacs is carbon emacs located in /Application/Emacs.app which just opens when clicking on it, or alternatively, I can open it in with the terminal:

```
open /Application/MyApp.app
```

Finally the title question: How can I make Makefile using the Emacs.app on the applications directory? I hope someone here knows the answer, or can point me to alternatives.

regards,
Jeroen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 bash-3.2$ EMACSLOADPATH=/usr/share/emacs/22.1/site-lisp:/usr/share/emacs/22.1/lisp emacs - batch -eval '(print "hi")'

 "hi"  
 bash-3.2$ emacs -batch -eval '(print "hi")'
 Cannot open load file: subst-ksc
 bash-3.2$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bash-3.2$ emacs -batch -eval '(print emacs-version)'
Cannot open load file: subst-ksc

bash-3.2$ unset EMACSLOADPATH

bash-3.2$ emacs -batch -eval '(print emacs-version)'

"22.1.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error `Cannot open load file: subst-ksc` on OS X Maverick running

```
cask exec emacs --no-site-file --no-site-lisp --batch \
     \
    -f batch-byte-compile projectile.el
```

I solved it with the method given [here](http://blog.danielgempesaw.com/post/86000064176/cannot-open-load-file-subst-ksc-os-x-10-9-2-emacs).

Replace the `/usr/bin/emacs` file by the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@"
```

With that manner the `emacs` command will run your actual Emacs.